# ¿Cómo obtener el vector de valores binarios de un problema de programación lineal?

Tags: r, optimización, binario

Hola tengo el siguiente código en R que se usa para calcular los objetos que se pueden introducir en una caja, en función de su peso (w), sin que superen el límite de peso permitido (P) y que sumen el de mayor valor (v) posible. Sí calcula bien la suma de valores de los objetos, pero no calcula el vector con valores binarios que indica los que entran (1) y los que no entran (0)

```
w <- c(3, 4, 1, 5) # pesos
v <- c(1, 4, 5, 7) # precios
P <- 7             # límite de peso
n <- 4             # numero de objetos
caja <- function(w, v, P, n){
  matr <- matrix(0, n+1, P+1)
  id <- rep(0, n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:P){
      if(w[i] > j){
        matr[i+1, j+1] <- matr[i, j+1]
      } else{
        matr[i+1, j+1] <- max(matr[i, j+1], matr[i, j+1-w[i]]+v[i])
        if(matr[i+1, j+1] > matr[i, j+1]){
          id[i] <- 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(list(val = matr[n+1, P+1],id = id))
}
result <-caja(w, v, W, n)
result$val # Resultado: 12
result$id  # Resultado esperado (1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo la forma en que tu función pueda retornar las combinaciones que maximicen el precio, realmente no entiendo lo que estás intentando hacer, por ejemplo, no veo que de alguna forma estés verificando cada posible combinación, por que el problema en cierta forma es simple: tienes que probar todas las combinaciones de elementos, quedarte solo con aquellas que no superen el precio máximo y luego con aquellas que ofrezcan el precio mayor.

Sin el enfoque iterativo, creo que el problema se resuelve determinando todas las combinaciones, desde seleccionar los 4 elementos hasta la combinación que no tienen ninguno:

```
n <- length(w)
perm <- gtools::permutations(2, n, repeats.allowed=TRUE) == 1
perm
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[11,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[12,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[13,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[14,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[15,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[16,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Con esto, cada fila representa una posible combinación del vector original, ahora está claro que solo hay que iterar por cada fila, validar si la combinación no supera el peso máximo, y con aquellas posibles, ver cual nos da el precio máximo:

```
caja <- function(w, v, P) {
  n <- length(w)
  perm <- gtools::permutations(2, n, repeats.allowed=TRUE) == 1
  pesos <- apply(perm, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(w[x]))
  precios <- apply(perm, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(v[x]))

  seleccionados <- perm[pesos <= P & precios == max(precios[pesos <= P]), ,drop=FALSE]

  return(
    list(val = max_precio,
       id = apply(seleccionados, 1, FUN = function(x) as.numeric(x)))
  )
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
result <- caja(w, v, P)
result$val

[1] 12

result$id

     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    1
[4,]    1
```